# Pass generic method as parameter to another method

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, .net-4.5

This has been asked before (I think), but looking through the previous answers I still haven't been able to figure out what I need.

Lets say I have a private method like:

```
private void GenericMethod<T, U>(T obj, U parm1)
```

Which I can use like so:

```
GenericMethod("test", 1);
GenericMethod(42, "hello world!");
GenericMethod(1.2345, "etc.");
```

How can I then pass my `GenericMethod` to another method so that I can then call it in that method in a similar way? e.g.:

```
AnotherMethod("something", GenericMethod);

...

public void AnotherMethod(string parm1, Action<what goes here?> method)
{
    method("test", 1);
    method(42, "hello world!");
    method(1.2345, "etc.");
}
```

I just can't get my head around this!  What do I need to specify as the generic parameters to `Action` in `AnotherMethod`?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass into `AnotherMethod` not a single delegate of some specific type, but a thing which contructs delegates. I think this can only be done using reflection or dynamic types:

```
void Run ()
{
    AnotherMethod("something", (t, u) => GenericMethod(t, u));
}

void GenericMethod<T, U> (T obj, U parm1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", typeof(T).Name, typeof(U).Name);
}

void AnotherMethod(string parm1, Action<dynamic, dynamic> method)
{
    method("test", 1);
    method(42, "hello world!");
    method(1.2345, "etc.");
}
```

Note that `(t, u) => GenericMethod(t, u)` cannot be replaced with just `GenericMethod`.

Comment: That's what I was starting to assume. Damn, but thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider using an intermediate class (or implement an interface):

```
class GenericMethodHolder {
    public void GenericMethod<T, U>(T obj, U parm1) {...};
}

public void AnotherMethod(string parm1, GenericMethodHolder holder)
{
    holder.GenericMethod("test", 1);
    holder.GenericMethod(42, "hello world!");
    holder.GenericMethod(1.2345, "etc.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to post another solution that I found usefull for a while, especially with caching. When I do a Get from Cache, and the cache item doesnt exist, I call the provided function to get the data, cache it and return. But, this can be used in your specific way too.

Your other method would need a signature similar to this, where `getItemCallback` is the `GenericMethod()` you want to be executed. Example has been cleared down for brevity.

```
public static T AnotherMethod<T>(string key, Func<T> _genericMethod ) where T : class
{
    result = _genericMethod(); //looks like default constructor but the passed in params are in tact.
    //... do some work here 
    return otherData as T;
}
```

Then you would call your `AnotherMethod()` as follows

```
var result = (Model)AnotherMethod("some string",() => GenericMethod(param1,param2));
```

I know its about several months later but maybe it will help the next person, as I forgot how to do this and couldn't find any similar answer on SO.